# Does a UNIQUE INDEX still index (though not constrain) the NULL values?

Tags: mysql

For example, a table with:

- id INT PRIMARY KEY
- firstName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
- lastName VARCHAR(20) NULL
- INDEX UNIQUE (firstName, lastName)

My understanding is that for rows with `lastName IS NULL`, there will be no constraint checking regardless of `firstName`. (Because `NULL` are not considered equal to each other.)

But I wanted to ask if those values are actually recorded, on-disk, into the index.

For example if I wanted to select all rows where firstName is "Mary". Is it possible that the index would be used to answer this query rather than the full text row entries?

Comment: What does indexing the null values have to do with whether it uses the index for `firstName = 'Mary'`? That's not a null value, so it will be in the index, and the index will be used.

Comment: In MySQL (InnoDB storage engine), yes. Also [yes in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/210292/does-postgresql-index-null-values). But for the sake of interest, this is [not true in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164623/oracle-index-for-null-values) and [not true in Microsoft SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687213/does-sql-server-index-null-values-in-a-non-clustered-non-unique-index), though workarounds exist for those brands.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, null values are in the index.

```
MySQL [bbodb_test]> create table test_index(c1 int null, c2 int null, unique(c1, c2));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.007 sec)

MySQL [bbodb_test]> insert into test_index values (null, null);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.002 sec)

MySQL [bbodb_test]> insert into test_index values (null, null);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.001 sec)

MySQL [bbodb_test]> explain select * from test_index where c1 is null;
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test_index | NULL       | ref  | c1            | c1   | 5       | const |    2 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+--------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.001 sec)
```

As you can see, it's using the index to satisfy `WHERE c1 is null`.